# Iterate row comparison over a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to compare similarities in students' test responses. So for students A, B, C, and D, I want to compare how many times each possible pair of students had the same answers. For example, A & B answered 5/7 questions the same, A & C answered 4/7 questions the same, etc. I'd end up with just a single column where the rows reflect each unique pair.

Here's an example data frame:

```
      Student Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5
      A       1  3  2  4  1
      B       1  2  4  1  1
      C       2  4  4  2  1
      D       3  1  2  3  4
      E       3  3  1  2  1
```

So far I've got pairs set up using combn:

```
    test<-combn(Book1$Student,2)
    compare<-lapply(1:ncol(test), function(x) rbind(Book1[Book1$Student==test[1,x], ],
                                   Book1[Book1$Student==test[2,x], ]))
```

This produces a list with unique comparisons, but I can't figure out how to sum identical responses across rows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combn

```
combn(1:nrow(Book1), 2, function(indices){
  sum(Book1[indices[1], 2 : 6] == Book1[indices[2], 2 : 6])
})
```

Comment: When I try that code, I get this output:

        [1] 0 1 0 1 1 0.  

What I'd expect to see if it was iterating through the combinations of rows would be 2 1 1 2 2 0 1 2 1. What's the indices function doing in the code you provided?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using a *self join* after reshaping `Book1` from wide to long format:

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(setDT(Book1)[
  , Student := ordered(Student)], id.vars = "Student")
long[long, on = .(variable, value)][
  , .N, by = .(Student, i.Student)][
    Student < i.Student][
      order(Student, i.Student)]
```

> ```
>    Student i.Student N
> 1:       A         B 2
> 2:       A         C 1
> 3:       A         D 1
> 4:       A         E 2
> 5:       B         C 2
> 6:       B         E 1
> 7:       C         E 2
> 8:       D         E 1
> ```

Alternatively, a symmetric matrix with the number of identical answers between any two students can be returned by

```
long <- melt(setDT(Book1), id.vars = "Student")
dcast(long[long, on = .(variable, value)][, .N, by = .(Student, i.Student)], 
      Student ~ i.Student, fill = 0)
```

> ```
>    Student A B C D E
> 1:       A 5 2 1 1 2
> 2:       B 2 5 2 0 1
> 3:       C 1 2 5 0 2
> 4:       D 1 0 0 5 1
> 5:       E 2 1 2 1 5
> ```